# Blazor Application /_blazor/disconnect statuscode 400

Tags: nginx, webserver, blazor, disconnect

my blazor app seems to work but im trying to understand why I'm getting a 400error as seen in the screenshot.

Who can give me a HINT for what Blazor needs technically the "disconnect" ?

[SCREENSHOT-disconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeQdn.png)

I'm running everything on a NGINX webserver.

thx Fabio

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write good and concise questions. You should probably provide some code samples of what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug reported for this issue here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30316

> Blazor.server.js not respecting configureSignalR builder defined
> url/path for disconnnects

As a work-around, I added this to `Startup.cs` in the `Configure` method:

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
rewriteOptions.AddRewrite("_blazor/disconnect", "/_blazor/disconnect", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

That call happens here in the code on the window unload event and is used to tell the signalr server that you are disconnecting.

If you are seeing a lot of these it may be that your proxy is not configured correctly for websocket connections.

```
window.addEventListener(
    'unload',
    () => {
      const data = new FormData();
      const circuitId = circuit.circuitId!;
      data.append('circuitId', circuitId);
      navigator.sendBeacon('_blazor/disconnect', data);
    },
    false
  );
```